# Anthos Service Mesh/Istio CORS not enabled

Tags: google-cloud-platform, istio, google-anthos

I'm trying to enable CORS on a GKE cluster with Anthos Service Mesh 1.8 using the Istio ingress gateway, but CORS header aren't returned correctly.

Here the Service configuration

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: my-service
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-service
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: ksa
      containers:
        - name: my-service
          image: <my image>
          ports:
            - name: http-server
              containerPort: 8080
```

and ingress configuration

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway 
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: istio-ingress
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - istio-gateway
  http:
    - name: default-public-route
      route:
        - destination:
            host: my-service
      corsPolicy:
        allowOrigins:
          - exact: "*"
        allowMethods:
          - GET
          - POST
          - PATCH
          - PUT
          - DELETE
          - OPTIONS
        allowCredentials: false
        allowHeaders:
          - authorization
        maxAge: "24h"
```

I'm also using [this](https://extendsclass.com/rest-client-online.html) online rest client to test the endpoint, and I get different reponses based if i use http prefix or not

with `<ingress ip>/mypath` I get 403 Forbidden error while with `http://<ingress ip>/mypath` i get a generic CORS not enabled. If I execute the api from Postman all works correctly but CORS headers are not returned. I also tried to set CORS directly from Flask application but nothing changed.

Any idea on how to solve?

Thanks

Comment: Could you try with `allowOrigins: - regex: '*'`?

Comment: well if regex, it should probably be `.*` . But I think, exact with `*` should work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, I have just tested it.

```
allowOrigins:
 - exact: "*"
```

In my experience, the Istio CORS options are a rather thin wrapper around generic CORS functionality, so I guess the real problem is not about Istio, but the CORS configuration.

Maybe something is wrong with `allowCredentials` or `allowHeaders`. Also if you have an Istio `AuthorizationPolicy`, HTTP `OPTIONS` calls should probably be allowed for pre-flight requests.

Comment: I think the problem was `Content-Type` header passed with a `GET` request